# Can the value of 'c' be found out without a quadratic equation?

Tags: triangles, quadratics

Given the expression to calculate the square of the radius of an incircle of a triangle is

$r^2 = {\frac{(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}{s}}$

Given $a,b,r$ are known can the value of $c$ be found out without a quadratic equation ? Here $s$ stands for the semi perimeter which is $s={\frac{a+b+c}{2}}$

Comment: The quadratic equation is useful, but never required. You can always complete the square instead. In this case, there's no c^2, so it's possible this isn't even a quadratic equation (s^2 does appear in the problem, but you're not solving for s).

Comment: @barrycarter Yes there is $c^2$ just by simplifying the above expression in order to get $c$ as the subject of the formula we land up with $c^2$. Could please show me how you are not ending up with any squares ?

Comment: @barrycarter Please see what $s$ really stands for.

Comment: My mistake, so I'll stick to my first comment: completing the square can always replace the quadratic equation.

Comment: @ng.newbie That equation is a *cubic* in $c\,$, not a quadratic.

Comment: @dxiv Exactly so it is basically an equation of a higher degree than one. Any way I can avoid and directly get the value of $s$

Comment: @barrycarter I am sorry, but what do you mean by completing the square ?

Comment: @ng.newbie Not that I am aware of.

Comment: @dxiv Any idea what completing the square means ?

Comment: @ng.newbie See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square) for example. It doesn't apply to *cubic* equations, though.